# Can I use a Microsoft SQL Server 2008(SP1_-10.0.2531.0 -Express Edition for a Production SharePoint 2010 Farm?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sql-server-2008, sql-express

I was told to fix some issues on sharepoint 2010 farm having single server installation. When i checked the SSMS, I came to know that they have installed use a
**Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)**

Is this a correct installation procedure? Will I have to switch to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) **Standard** or **Enterprise** environment?
Will MSFT support/recommends this express edition on a sp 2010 single server Production env?

Also , i am facing the logs issue on teh c drive of this prod.server. every 30 minutes some 150 MB files of log files were generated hence deeply affecting the appln performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported but express addition has some limitation I.e max size of content db which is 4gb.

Yes MSFT provide the support for this type of deployment as they mentioned in the hardware and software requirement.

I would highly recommend to move the installation to regular edition if you see the growth because once you hit the maximum size of db then it will be an issue.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx#section4

Comment: Thanks Waqas. Since its a single server farm , should i move the complete sql to a new server ? They were facing performance issues while accessing the FBA enabled web application and issues populated with user management of aspnetdb - like password reset / access denied regularly. etc.

Comment: Is it installed as a server farm like single server of sharepoint and separate server for sql server? Or is it install with single server with builtin database

Comment: how can i determine that installed on a single server with builtin DB? or separate sql server? when i did the SSSMS and select @@version , i got the version name , as SQL SERVE SP1 express edition. i am having a single server with SP 2010 in installed. am confused about your question, the sql is NOT installed on a separate server. its on the same  server itself.

Comment: Are sharepoint and sql on same server?

Comment: YES. SP 2010 and SQL SERVER are on the same server.  UPDATE : i am cheking the sql : there are 2 instances . 1) sharepoint 2) "sharepoint\sharepoint" . in the  "sharepoint" instance , aspnetdb is created  with 2 contentdbs. but this is not the instance where the SP 2010 is installed. The other instance "sharepoint\sharepoint"  is having all the SP default DBs likes _config, search, mms, user profile etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to answer this on but on general any SharePoint version can use the previous to the coming version of SQL Server. SharePoint 2010 need to run on SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 up to SQL Server 2012. For SharePoint 2013 can run on SQL Server 2012/2012 R2 up SQL Server 2014 / 2014 R2.

So the answer is Yes, supported! (SQL Server Express isn't supported)

Or at least for development. In production you need to have a separate SQL Server and at least one SharePoint Server for a very small environment.

Reference: [Hardware and software requirements (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx)